# Why do I see my website's URL links on Google Analyitcs keywords list?

Tags: google-analytics, keywords, not-provided

Is it normal ? Why do I see my sites URL on Google Analytics keywords list, as in

> np - /software-application/
>
> np - /contact-us/

`np` I understand is **not provided** is it. But why is my URL listed?

Comment: are you running display ads?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior in my Google Analytics account.

Comment: No @prasad i'm not running any display ads... and i'm still getting my keywords listed as " np-/software-pricing ".